# reading the HANDLE_IN and HANDLE_ERR from open3

Tags: perl

I am using open 3 for executing my python script I want to see output of handle_out and handle_error How can i see it .I am doing something like below? It prints

```
sel : IO::Select=ARRAY(0x18e15040)


local (*HANDLE_IN, *HANDLE_OUT,*HANDLE_ERR);
       open3( \*HANDLE_IN, \*HANDLE_OUT, \*HANDLE_ERR, "@args")  or die "open3 failed $!\n";

 my $sel = new IO::Select;
        $sel->add(\*HANDLE_OUT,\*HANDLE_ERR);
        print "sel : $sel";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use IO::Select. Those are just normal filehandles like any other.

```
while (my $line = <HANDLE_OUT>) {
    print $line;
}
```

It'd be better to use a modern style, though, as presented in the docs for [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html).

```
my ($wtr, $rdr, $err);
use Symbol 'gensym'; $err = gensym;
$pid = open3($wtr, $rdr, $err,
    'some cmd and args', 'optarg', ...);
```

---

What follows demonstrates that the above advice is wrong as it leads to deadlocks. The following program never exits because of the above advice:

```
perl -MIPC::Open3=open3 -E'
    my $pid = open3(
       local *TO_CHILD,
       local *FROM_CHILD,
       local *FROM_CHILD_ERROR,
       "perl",
       "-E" => q{say STDERR "x"x(64*1024); say "y";},
    );
    say "Getting STDOUT";
    print while <FROM_CHILD>;
    say "Getting STDERR";
    print while <FROM_CHILD_ERR>;
    waitpid($pid, 0);
'
```

Comment: Actually, you do need to use `select` (or threads or non-blocking handles) if you want to avoid a deadlock

Comment: Seeing as you accepted this answer, I guess you didn't see my comment or you didn't believe me, so I added a snippet to the answer that shows why this answer is wrong.

Comment: Also, `open3` has some bugs when you pass lexical handles. While I'd recommend lexical handles any other time, the OP should keep using globals with `open3`.

Answer (score 2):

`open3` is still a rather low-level solution. It handles *many* things for you, but it doesn't help you with handling inter-process communication (ipc).

If you want to read from the child's STDOUT and STDERR independently, or if you both send and receive data from the child, you run afoul of a deadlock.

While it is possible to use `select` to avoid deadlocks, it's VERY complicated. I don't recommend you go down that route. I recommend that you use [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun3) (simplest) or [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun) (more features) instead of `open3`, bypassing the entire issue.